# .htaccess file is not working on Apache Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting

I have hosted my site on www.hostmoster.com, I have written .htaccess file for URL rewritting, it was working properly since last 1 year.. but today they have made some upgrade in their Apache Server.. and now my .htaccess file is not working properly. the contents of my file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|functions\.php|showpopup\.php|signup\.php|chat|tmp|extras|services|flash|data|images|forum|business|css|scripts|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please help me out.. Apache Server version is 2.2.11.. The problem i am facing is that for each of page request it opens the index.php page

Comment: Ask at Hostmonster support. You're paying them, they should be able to help you, especially if the problem is in their configuration.

Comment: How about asking them what have changed since the upgrade.

Comment: http://helpdesk.hostmonster.com/

Comment: On last line I have made a change I have change the [L] to [R].. it has started working.. but it is showing index.php in URL now.. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ...

> Note:
>
> If you want to call your .htaccess
>   file something else, you can change
>   the name of the file using the
>   AccessFileName directive. For example,
>   if you would rather call the file
>   .config then you can put the following
>   in your server configuration file:
>
> AccessFileName .config

From [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can be for two reason. One for the permission of the file and second is for the disable to execute .htaccess by web server. Use this link to check apache configuration to execute .htaccess file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

It is sure in shared server you will not be allow to access of .conf file but you can ask  problem to support team, they can help you.